# Probit regression in R giving singular Hessian matrix

Tags: r, panel-data, probit, singular-matrix

I am trying to run a probit regression using panel data in R by first computing the log likelihood and then using the `optim` function to optimize.

1. Scale of predictor variables: The predictor variables that I have vary in scale significantly. Some of the variables are in tens while some are in '000s. When I am trying to run the `optim` function, it frequently gives the error message: `vmmin is not finite`. So I have to be extremely careful in choosing the initial values. And some of these initial values are as small as 0.0001. Is this standard in probit? Or do we need to normalize the predictor variables before using probit?
2. I have a few variables that are computed within the estimation code, i.e., some of the parameters that are being estimated are used to calculate these inbuilt covariates. When I run the full model with all such inbuilt parameters, the `optim` function gives me a singular Hessian matrix. Again, I am not sure what the singularity of the hessian implies. When I the add the inbuilt covariates one at a time, the Hessian is not singular.

Has anyone encountered such problems before? Please advise.

Comment: This is potentially a good question, but you need to include some more detail about your data and your problem, ideally a minimum working example of what you are trying.